# how to insert a infomation on a table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my form on models.py

```
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
     itemname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    itemwording = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    notes = forms.CharField()
    abundance = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10)
    collunit = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    litref = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    litkey = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10)
    litrefdetail = forms.CharField()
    collcode =  forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    specimenno = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    speciesid = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10)
    sorder = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    disabled = forms.BooleanField(required = True)
```

This is my view.py

```
 def additem(request):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            itemnameNEW = form.cleaned_data['itemname']
            itemwordingNEW = form.cleaned_data['itemwording']
            notesNEW = form.cleaned_data['notes']
            abundanceNEW = form.cleaned_data['abundance']
            collunitNEW = form.cleaned_data['collunit']
            litrefNEW = form.cleaned_data['litref']
            litkeyNEW = form.cleaned_data['litkey']
            litrefdetailNEW = form.cleaned_data['litrefdetail']
            collcodeNEW =  form.cleaned_data['collcode']
            specimennoNEW = form.cleaned_data['specimenno']
            speciesidNEW = form.cleaned_data['speciesid']
            sorderNEW = form.cleaned_data['sorder']
            disabledNEW = form.cleaned_data['disabled']

            newitem = Item(itemname=itemnameNEW, itemwording=itemwordingNEW, notes=notesNEW, abundance=abundanceNEW, collunit=collunitNEW, litref=litrefNEW, litkey=litkeyNEW, litrefdetail=litrefdetailNEW, collcode=collcodeNEW,specimenno=specimennoNEW, speciesid=speciesidNEW,sorder=sorderNEW,disabled=disabledNEW )
            newitem.save();
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/jalo/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/nojalo/')

    else:
        form = ItemForm()

    return render_to_response('tbl/additem.html', {'form': form})
```

When i submit the form i get

```
     IntegrityError at /login/manageitem/additem/
      duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tbl_item_pkey"
```

I just want to insert information on a table using django

Answer (score 1):

The data you've posted doesn't indicate the source of the problem. Did you clear your database and run `syncdb` when you last changed your models?

The error you're seeing relates to trying to introduce a duplicate value into a column which must be unique, constrained at the database level. You have an object that's trying to be saved with a duplicate pk value.

That said, your keyvalueNEW scheme is not at all the right way of going about doing that. You probably want to be using ModelForms instead.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/